# woocommerce checkout tax not reflected into the order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

anybody can help on this?

I've added a woocommerce_form_field (checkbox) on the checkout page in order to calculate a different tax depending on that checkbox.
Once checked, the checkout form is updated accordingly with this new tax rate.
My issue is that when I press over the button "Place Order", the total amount doesn't reflect the modification of the tax, it takes the standard tax instead of the new tax.

```
    /**
 * Add checkbox field to the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_ER_field');
function my_custom_checkout_ER_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my-new-field-ER"><h3>'.__('My ER Checkbox: ').'</h3>';
    //input name=shipping_method
    woocommerce_form_field( 
        'shipping_method_pp',   //key
        array(                  //args
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'class'         => array('input-checkbox ER_checkbox shipping_fields'),
            'label'         => __('ER Checkbox'),
            'required'  => false,
        ), 
        $checkout->get_value( 'shipping_method_pp' )    //value
    );

    echo '</div>';
}

//A continuación tengo la función que detecta si está pulsado o no y luego debería actualizar el precio en consecuencia.
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'checkout_update_order_review_pp' );
function checkout_update_order_review_pp( $post_data ) {

  parse_str( $post_data, $post_data );

  if ( '1' == $post_data['shipping_method_pp'] ) {
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );

  }
}

function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {
    $tax_class = 'iva-normal-con-r-e';
    return $tax_class;
}
```

If anybody can help me on this, I'd be really greatful!!
I add some screenshot below (in a commend below).

Cheers!

Comment: Some screenshot about the above issue.
Standard tax: <http://ewamfy.com/standard_tax.png>
After apply new tax: <http://ewamfy.com/order_details.png>
But order doesn't reflect the new tax: <http://ewamfy.com/order_details.png>

Comment: The tax class need to be changed by products on cart object (as you can have different tax classes set in your products and not for the order… so this is much more complicated to make it work. Also your third screenshot is the same than 2nd